# Unable to exec mysql command and to use $MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD with mysql docker in Windows

Tags: mysql, powershell, docker

From powershell console, I manage to run mysql command inside my mysql docker:

```
docker exec mysql-container mysql -u root -psecret -e 'show databases;'
```

But if I want to replace my password by MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD, it doesn't work anymore:

```
docker exec mysql-container mysql -u root -p$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD -e 'show databases;'
# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

It seems powershell interprets $MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD and pass it as empty to the container.

Other commands I tried:

```
docker exec mysql-container sh -c "mysql -u root -p$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD -e 'show databases;'"
# Enter password: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

docker exec mysql-container sh -c 'mysql -u root -p$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD -e "show databases;"'
# ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

Comment: seems like you are in the window. you can use `"\`"`. https://serverfault.com/questions/47811/what-is-the-literal-escape-character-in-powershell

Answer (score 1):

Try with `-it` as it will exit because you are not allocating `tty`, also add escape character before password, otherwise, it will look for environment variables from the host, not inside the container.

```
docker exec -it mysql-container bash -c " mysql  -u root -p"\$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" -e 'show databases;'"
```

Comment: With your command I get `Enter password: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`. Escaping the dollar doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I finally manage to get the good amount of quotes to make the command run:

```
docker exec mysql-container sh -c 'mysql -u root -p$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD -e ''show databases;'''
```